# Scrolling with two UITableView in a single touch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have weird design scenario where I have used two **UITableviews** - one at the top and another at the bottom, The top one is inside the cell of and other one.

Initially, both the Tableview's **scroll** is enabled.

**Only** if the top **Tableview** moves **upward** then I am disabling the scroll of the top tableview so that the bottom one scrolls.

```
tableView1.isScrollEnabled = false
```

It works but **not** in a **single touch**. I have to remove the first touch first then only in the second touch the bottom Tableview scrolls.

Is there any way so that I can make scrollable to the bottom tableview in a single touch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why cant you use single tableview with two sections??

Comment: Might recommend using a UIGesturerRecognizer. Would get a little complex with determining the content offset of the tableView, but UIGestureRecognizer has functions which are regularly called and output the instantaneous distance dragged, you could match this with the original tableView offset and then know when to disable scrolling on the smaller tableViews.

Answer (score 0):

You can take both the UITableView in a UIScrollView and assign the following class to both the UITableView.

You don't need to play with the isScrollEnabled property.

Remember to give the intrinsic size to tableView as well

[image: Choose Intrinsic Size]

```
class DynamicTableView: UITableView {

override var contentSize:CGSize {
    didSet {
        if contentSize == CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 0.0) {
            self.separatorStyle = .none
            contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50.0)
        } else {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
}}
```

Comment: Actually the second tableview is inside the cell of the first tableview.

Comment: Still, you can use this

Comment: Ok. Let me try. I will let you know. Please reply if need any help further regarding this.